# How to get value of user-emacs-directory from shell?

Tags: emacs

I'm writing a script to automatically install some elisp.  I'd like to find the value of `user-emacs-directory` so that I can copy the file to the right directory.  Is there any way to do this from the shell?

I was hoping it would work to run:

```
$ emacs --batch --eval="(print user-emacs-directory)"
Symbol's value as variable is void: user-emacs-directory
```

but as you can see that was not fruitful.  Then I tried loading my `.emacs` file first:

```
$ emacs --batch -l ~/.emacs --eval="(print user-emacs-directory)"
Loading /Users/noah/dotfiles/emacs/init.el (source)...
Symbol's function definition is void: global-visual-line-mode
```

but that also chokes.  Googling hasn't led me to an answer yet.  Any ideas?

**edit**: The specific problem was that I was using an old version of Emacs (22.1.1).  Running Emacs 24.4.1 works:

```
$ emacs -l ~/.emacs --batch --eval="(print user-emacs-directory)" 2>/dev/null

"~/dotfiles/emacs"
```

(which is the custom value I've set in my own `~/.emacs` file)

Note that I'm redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` to suppress some loading messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me on vanilla `GNU Emacs 24.5.1` shipped with Ubuntu:

```
$ emacs -Q --batch --eval="(princ user-emacs-directory)"                                                                                                                            
~/.emacs.d/
```

note `princ` instead of `print` to avoid extra whitespace and quote marks.

Comment: Ah, the problem actually was that I was running an old version of Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

`--batch` implies `-q` which means there *is* no `user-emacs-directory`

*edit: Ugh. No, `-q` doesn't mean that at all. As sds points out, the proposed code should probably be working. That'll teach me to jump to conclusions. I'd delete this answer, but as the original approach evidentially doesn't work for Noah for some reason, I'll leave this here just in case it still helps...*

Typically you just want `$HOME/.emacs.d/`

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Find Init` <kbd>RET</kbd> for more info.